# Light-to-heat-conversion (LTHC)

Tags: thermodynamics, laser, laser-interaction

Can somebody explain what is light-to-heat-conversion? how it happens, and what it requires to happen?

Comment: Have you used a microwave oven? Have you "felt" the warmth of the sun?

Answer (score 1):

Heat is movement of particles.  The faster the particles move or vibrate, the hotter the material of which they are part becomes.  In order for light to generate heat, the wavelength of the light must resonate with particles in the material the light strikes, and must make them vibrate.  This may happen at the molecular level.  For example, long infrared wavelengths in sunlight resonate well with some molecules and set them in motion, raising their temperature.

Another way that light can generate heat is when shorter wavelengths are absorbed by electrons in atoms, raising the energy state of the atom or molecule.  When the atom or molecule returns to its ground state, some of the excess energy of the absorbed photons is thrown off as vibration.  The particles vibrate and rotate and transfer that movement to other particles in the material, raising its temperature.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What is the best and cheapest way to make this reaction at home? or in a simple laboratory? what would be the reactant and would be the laser wavelength? Would you also please refer me to a good literature about it?

Comment: @NovicePhysicist : If you have an infrared light bulb, such as are sold for some bathroom ceiling fan fixtures, you can put a brick under it and witness the brick heating up. If you put a piece of metal outside in the sunlight on a windless day, you can place a thermometer in the shade under the metal, but in contact with the metal, and note that its temperature increases. Be careful NOT to look directly at the infrared bulb, at the sun, or at sunlight reflecting off the metal.